# Coffescript + Ionic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova, coffeescript, ionic-framework

I am looking to build a hybrid mobile app using Ionic framework in CoffeeScript.

The functionality that the app would have is login/signup; take and upload picture to store in mongodb.

What is the full stack recommendations for this app?

https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic covers the client side (except it is in JavaScript and I will find a way to make it work with CoffeeScript)

On the server-side; Mongoose + Passport + what else do I need?

https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic

https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-Node-Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend simply using firebase.com for the backend, which it self run on NodeJS, in addition to Scala, Netty.io and Javascript. Their authentification service, Simple Login, is key in hand and you don't really have to write any backend code.

You can authenticate your users through

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Github
- Google
- Anonymous
- A simple email and password authentication
- Custom authentication

You can always store images in base64-encoded format. If your images are larger than 10 mb, which is their limit, you can always split them up in 10 mb chunks.

Another point worth mentionning is that Ionic being based on AngularJS, you can use AngularFire which is the officially supported AngularJS binding for Firebase. The combination of Angular and Firebase provides a three-way data binding between HTML, JavaScript, and your Firebase backend.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

I did 2-3 ionic apps using Firebase as my backend and it saved me a lot of time.